# Alternativas para as funções do File System com node js

Tags: node.js, sistema-de-arquivos

Ao executar uma função de abrir um arquivo muito grande ,o mesmo me retornou esse erro

```
Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters
    at stringSlice (buffer.js:602:44)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:668:10)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:385:41)
    at readArq (/var/www/Split-xml-document/split.js:8:17)
    at geraArquivos (/var/www/Split-xml-document/split.js:26:15)
    at /var/www/Split-xml-document/split.js:63:11
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
(node:26810) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:26810) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

A função que executei foi a seguinte

```
function readArq(arq) {
  let arquivo = arq.replace(".bz2", "");
  //abre o arquivo wikipedia.part_20.xml
  let data = fs.readFileSync(cwd + "/dataset2/" + arquivo, "utf-8");
  return data;
}
```

O arquivo em questão está na faixa de 1Gb ,pelo que pesquisei ,o erro se dar por que a função não consegue abrir arquivos muito grandes, a pergunta é ,existe alguma outra função do node js que consegue abrir arquivos grandes,o arquivo é um .xml ,ou alguma opção em que posso usar a fs.readFileSync informando que o limite é 1Gb ou mais?

Comment: O que você quer fazer com esse arquivo?

Comment: Tenho uma outra função que divide ele ao meio pra facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Se você não vai fazer nenhum processamento usando o arquivo você pode só usar um stream para dividí-lo

Comment: sim ,o arquivo preciso processar ,eu divido ele ,e como ele divide exatamente ao meio,preciso pegar as configurações iniciais do primeiro arquivo e copiar pro segundo ,entre outras coisas

Comment: Você pode usar `stream` para realizar a transformação no arquivo que você deseja. [Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). O ideal é que você não leia toda a informação de uma vez e sim que só verifique qual linha é e que transfira para o arquivo 1 ou arquivo 2

Comment: Tem algum exemplo?não conheço essas funções

Comment: Depende, precisamos saber exatamente o que você precisa fazer com um arquivo, um exemplo de um arquivo pequeno e das saídas para sabermos o que você precisa de verdade